# Flutter + Firebase - How to dispose Listen events

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a main widget in which based on the boolean value I show two different widgets

```
drawScreen ? DrawScreenWidget() : GuessScreenWidget(),
```

On the GuessScreenWidget() I have Listen events

```
 sketchStroke = databaseReference
        .child('ref')
        .onValue
        .listen((data) {
 });
```

So when the boolean changes, the screen moves between the two widgets, but the listen events on GuessScreenWidget don't get cancelled. I tried to use dispose but it doesn't work.

```
  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    sketchStroke.cancel();
  }
```

I would appreciate if someone could guide how to cancel the listen event when the GuessScreenWidget is switched to DrawScreenWidget. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("handleCountM").limit(1).snapshots();

late StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamSubscription;
  

void handleDelete() {
    streamSubscription = myStream.listen((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        element.reference.delete();
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamSubscription.cancel(); //Cancel your subscription here.
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Your other alternative, would be to use a streambuilder, and it'll handle the subscription and termination for you.

> or you can use this

```
late CollectionReference reference;
  late StreamSubscription streamSubscription;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    reference = _firestore.collection(singleAuction.id.toString());
    streamSubscription = reference.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
      for (var element in querySnapshot.docChanges) {}
    });
        super.initState();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
   streamSubscription.cancel();
  }
```

Comment: What happens if firebase listener is in a repository?